# Set -Wno-dev in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I use the [SDL2 CMake Modules](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules) and include them in my CMakeLists.txt like this

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/sdl2)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_gfx REQUIRED)
```

There, they generate the warning

> CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.21.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message): 
> The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (SDL2main) 
> does not match the name of the calling package (SDL2).  This can lead to 
> problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables 
> (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern. 
> Call Stack (most recent call first): 
> cmake/sdl2/FindSDL2.cmake:318 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package) 
> This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

I don't care about that warning and want to suppress it. 
However, I don't want to pass `-Wno-dev` to the `cmake` command itself, I would rather set that flag in the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: There seems to be an open pull request to fix this. You could apply this instead of disabling the warning (might be safer)? https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules/pull/6/commits/6ee7dd0598e12732c52875605a2beda9b577a115

Comment: @SamBob this is mine) It fixes the mentioned warning and adds compatibility with CONFIG mode. I'd suggest to cherry pick those commits

Comment: https://github.com/ElDesalmado/sdl2-cmake-modules you can also use my fork, it has this warning fixed